# Splitting Array into new arrays and printing them with spaces

Tags: c#, arrays, sorting

This program will sort numbers and depending if they are greater than or less than 100, put them into their own array.

The problem I have is printing this array. I would like the last number on the line, to not be followed by a space. I have tried many many times to get this to work now and figured I'd ask here.

I know of `Console.Write("\b");` but I prefer to find a way of editing the loop so I don't have to do this. Here is the code:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;

class SplitArray
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int[] myArray = GetNumbersFromConsole();

        int[] smallNumbers = new int[myArray.Length];
        int[] bigNumbers = new int[myArray.Length];

        int bigIndex = 0;
        int littleIndex = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < myArray.Length; i++)
        {
            if(myArray[i] > 100)
            {
                bigNumbers[bigIndex++] = myArray[i];
            }
            else if(myArray[i] < 100)
            {
                smallNumbers[littleIndex++] = myArray[i];
            }
        }

        Console.Write("Big: ");

        for (int i = 1; i < bigIndex; ++i)
        {
            Console.Write(bigNumbers[i]);
            Console.Write(" ");
        }

        Console.WriteLine();
        //Console.WriteLine($"{bigNumbers[0]}");


        Console.Write("Little: ");

        for (int i = 0; i < littleIndex; i++)
        {
            Console.Write($"{smallNumbers[i]}");
            Console.Write(" ");
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    static int[] GetNumbersFromConsole()
    {
        int count = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        int[] result = new int[count];

        for (int i = 0; i < count; ++i)
        {
            result[i] = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        }

        return result;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just capture your `Console.Write(" ");` in an if statement.

```
if(i != littleIndex - 1)
{
  Console.Write(" ");
}
```

littleIndex - 1 is the last time your loop executes, so this will just prevent it from adding the trailing white space. Just do the same for your big numbers as you're printing them out.

Comment: I tried adding this to the code and ran the program.

The bigIndex for loop did not print the first number.

Maybe I misunderstood you?

Comment: Check the for loop for bigIndex. @emsimpson92's response doesn't affect bigIndex not printing the first number

Comment: I followed his instructions and added edits in both places. I have also tried this previously.

Comment: That's because you start at `i = 1` not `i = 0`

Comment: Ah yes, tried that now. It worked :) I solved it a second ago with a slight difference to yours, I will accept your answer :) Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

There is a builtin utility [*string.Join*](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/57a79xd0(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
var str = string.Join(" ",bigNumbers);
Console.WriteLine("Big: " + str);
```

Comment: Actually this methods does not have *anything* to do with linq and exists since .NET 2.0

Answer (score 0):

I was playing around some more and just thought I'd try posting the first object in the array before running this loop (also changed loop so the first item didn't get printed twice).

Thank you everyone - I solved it! :)

```
using System;
using System.Linq;

namespace Arrays
{
class SplitArray
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int[] myArray = GetNumbersFromConsole();

        int[] smallNumbers = new int[myArray.Length];
        int[] bigNumbers = new int[myArray.Length];

        int bigIndex = 0;
        int littleIndex = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < myArray.Length; i++)
        {
            if(myArray[i] > 100)
            {
                bigNumbers[bigIndex++] = myArray[i];
            }
            else if(myArray[i] < 100)
            {
                smallNumbers[littleIndex++] = myArray[i];
            }
        }

        Console.Write("Big: ");
        Console.Write($"{bigNumbers[0]} ");
        for (int i = 1; i < bigIndex; i++)
        {
            Console.Write(bigNumbers[i]);

            if (i != bigIndex - 1)
            {
                Console.Write(" ");
            }
        }

        Console.WriteLine();

        Console.Write("Little: ");

        Console.Write($"{smallNumbers[0]} ");

        for (int i = 1; i < littleIndex; i++)
        {
            Console.Write($"{smallNumbers[i]}");

            if (i != littleIndex - 1)
            {
                Console.Write(" ");
            }
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    static int[] GetNumbersFromConsole()
    {
        int count = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        int[] result = new int[count];

        for (int i = 0; i < count; ++i)
        {
            result[i] = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        }

        return result;
    }
}
}
```